# Cakephp 3.0 Form validation

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

I'm playing around with Cakephp 3.0 and wondering how I go about validating data which is not being saved to the database.

For example I know in the model (which appears to be now known as a "table") you add a validationDefault method to the model which is called automatically when data is being saved to the database i.e a new user is being added to the database. But how would I go about validating data from a login form which is not saving to the database and then show those errors?

For example on a user login, I would want to check whether fields have been entered, doesn't exceed a certain size etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from the official docs, you can instantiate a validator in your controller and validate your data by passing it `$this->request->data()`

```
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

...

$validator = new Validator();
$validator
    ->validatePresence('email')
    ->add('email', 'validFormat', [
        'rule' => 'email',
        'message' => 'E-mail must be valid'
    ])
    ->validatePresence('name')
    ->notEmpty('name', 'We need your name.')
    ->validatePresence('comment')
    ->notEmpty('comment', 'You need to give a comment.');

$errors = $validator->errors($this->request->data());
if (!empty($errors)) {
    // Send an email.
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html